# htaccess redirection not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have my `.htaccess` code as follows :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /annsenglishmediumschool
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.annsenglishmediumschool\.com$
    RewriteRule .* http://annsenglishmediumschool.com/index.php/%1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

What i need is when user types as  `(anystring).mysite.com` should go to `mysite.com/mycontroller/myaction/(anystring)`,to catch anystring in mycontroller. The problem is that it now takes `www` to the right as when i types `www.annsenglishmediumschool.com` it goes to `annsenglishmediumschool.com/index.php/www` ,

How to resolve this ? Thanks.

**EDIT** :   My cpanel redirects shows as follows :

```
    Domain:(.+?).annsenglishmediumschool.com
    Directory: /.* 
    Redirect Url :http://annsenglishmediumschool.com/index.php/%1
```

Any wrong with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a check to make sure it doesn't start with `www`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+?)\.annsenglishmediumschool\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^www
RewriteRule .* http://annsenglishmediumschool.com/index.php/%1 [L]
```

Comment: I think its taken as another website as its giving me this error when i types 'shops.annsenglishmediumschool.com' :"Sorry, the website shops.annsenglishmediumschool.com cannot be found"

Comment: Did you set up the subdomain? Search for "setting up a subdomain" in your cpanel or on google. Also, [check this out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: So is it needed to set up subdomains manually in cpanel ? Not work with .htaccess (when enter site as "subdomain.domain.com" )? i am in codeigniter ,so i dont know how its effective in setting up subdomains in cpanel

Comment: .htaccess works with apache -- the webserver -- it has nothing to do with CodeIgniter (although you can use both together). If you set up htaccess to redirect or point to a subdomain, the subdomain has to exist on the webserver for it to work. You set up the subdomain through your webserver/webhost; in your case you can use cpanel: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/SubDomains

Comment: OH WAIT, SORRY; you don't need a subdomain set up. I forgot you were redirecting subdomains to regular URL's. So you have to have a `shops` controller with an index function for shops.annsenglishmediumschool.com to work.

Comment: But when i creating subdomain , its asking 'document root' ,i think its not the way routing happens in codeigniter , it should go to sitename/controller/action and not via folder .

Comment: yeah for the previous comment,so the .htaccess will workout for that case ?

Comment: Yes, the htaccess should work. But you need a `shops` controller for when the page redirects to domain.com/index.php/shops

Comment: Yeeah i have the 'shops' controller,but when types shops.domain.com it says Sorry, the website shops.domain.com cannot be found.

Comment: Right. You will need to add an entry to your DNS configuration for the domain. Can do a CNAME or A *.domain.com to point everything at your server. Then htaccess will point it to the shops controller.

Comment: I added name:*.domain.com , TTL:14400 ,Class :IN ,Type: CNAME , Record :domain.com in my advanced DNS zone editor ,still not working! or will it take time to come in to effect ?

Comment: Well they need to be annsenglishmediumschool.com; but other than that looks right. You can try to lower ttl on A record to like 300 or something. Clear dns cache locally too. http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3aannsenglishmediumschool.com&run=toolpage

Comment: yeah i typed like that ,but still not going to the site when i types 'subdomain.domain.com' .Details are :name:*.domain.com , TTL:300 ,Class :IN ,Type: CNAME , Record :domain.com ,what is the link you given ?

Comment: I got it !!, i have to give port number in the place of Record (It should be Record:ip address)instead of domain name,thanks .